# How to make attractive dropdown menu using css3?

Tags: css

I have three tab..

home

services

account

```
<ul><li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Services</a></li>
<li><a href=#>Account</a></li></ul>
```

How do I apply css to list tab to show different mouseover color?

how to do this?

```
li {
   Background-color:#696969;
   display:Inline;
}
```

Comment: Attractive dropdown menu cannot be made by using 2 properties and a single rule block, also keep things lower case

Comment: yeah, that's wat i am asking. i am new to css. i don't know how to make more attractive. what are the property available to  make  more attractive menus using css3?

Comment: You should learn more CSS, see some examples online

Comment: ok alien.can we do animation in this mouse hover. when mouse hover i want populate tooltip with some short description about particular page information. how to achieve this?

Comment: definitely jquery or javascript.

Comment: i made what you asked here kind of: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/FtPvf/

Comment: with css only. Tool tip needs timing and that can get sooo complicated with css only.

Comment: for tat we need to use jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
li:hover {
background-color: New Color;
}
```

Here is a really simple dropdown menu I made
Html

```
<div id="newsletter" class="navigation">
<span style="display:block;" id="newsletterMain" href="index.html">Newsletter</span>
<a style="margin-top:19px; border-top: ridge thin rgba(0,0,0,.3);" class="month" href="index.html">Month</a>
<a class="month" href="index.html">Month</a>
<a class="monthLast" href="index.html">Month</a>
</div>
```

CSS
    #newsletter .month {
        display:block; margin-left:-11px;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        width:100%;
        height:0;
        border-bottom: ridge thin rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        background:#3D0F5F;
        font-size:1px;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
        -moz-transition:    all .5s;
        -ms-transition:     all .5s;
        -o-transition:      all .5s;
        transition:         all .5s;

```
}
#newsletter .monthLast {
    display:block; margin-left:-11px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    background:#3D0F5F;
    font-size:1px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition:    all .5s;
    -ms-transition:     all .5s;
    -o-transition:      all .5s;
    transition:         all .5s;

}
#newsletter:hover .month{
    display:block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height:auto;
    border-right: thin ridge #000;

    border-left: thin ridge #000;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity:1;


}

#newsletter:hover .monthLast {
    display:block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height:auto;
    border-right: thin ridge #000;
    border-bottom: thin ridge #000;
    border-left: thin ridge #000;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    font-size:18px;
    opacity:1;

}
#newsletterMain {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition:    all .5s;
    -ms-transition:     all .5s;
    -o-transition:      all .5s;
    transition:         all .5s;
}
#newsletterMain:hover {
    background: transparent;
    /*color:#BBAFFF;


    text-shadow: 0 0 15px #BB74FF;*/
}
#newsletter {
    border: thin ridge #FFF;
    border-top: none;
    background:#3D0F5F;
    color:#FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition:    all .5s;
    -ms-transition:     all .5s;
    -o-transition:      all .5s;
    transition:         all .5s;
}
#newsletter:hover {
    border: thin ridge #000;
    border-top: none;
    background:/*#CDA0FF*/#F8F8F8;
}
#newsletter #newsletterMain {
    color:#FFF;
}
#newsletter:hover #newsletterMain {
    color:#3D0F5F;
}
```

Comment: ok. how to make drop down list mouse hover here?

Comment: I think I added what you need in an edit.

Comment: I think, I can do.your post more useful..

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, mouseover (hover effects) can be achieved using [**:hover CSS pseudo-class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover).

```
li a:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gU34W/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. Like this you can makes menu as per your requorement.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
          ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
          ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
          li ul {display: none;}
          ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
          white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
          ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
          li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
          li:hover li {float: none;}
          li:hover a {background: #f00;}
          li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
          #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <ul id="drop-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice post man,nice work. I got it.